# ClickOnce deploy starts splash then quits

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

I have done a deployment on my WPF App using ClickOnce deployment. ALl worked on my computer but if I sent the app to some people that just want to see and test the program, the app won't work.

If they run setup.exe the splash screen opens, then when actuall App should open nothing happens.

I have tried to install .Net runtime, no better. Even if I give them the Release folder its the same..

Any ideas? Did I do something bad with the coding?

Comment: Have you checked the application event log for any unhandled .net runtime errors?

Comment: I recently found out that error was because of two libraries. "system.speech" and sqllite. For the release to work I had to delete system.speech from my project and copy some dlls for sqllite..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with similar problems:

I recently found out that error was because of two libraries. `system.speech` and sqlite. For the release to work I had to delete `system.speech` from my project and copy some dlls for sqlite.